# Shifting packages between different versions of python

Tags: python, python-2.7

My mac has two versions of Python,

one installed in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip`

and the other `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`

I have plenty of packages installed in the second directory. How do I move all those packages under the first python ?

Also How do I force my mac to use the first Python ?

Comment: Have you tried virtual environments?

Answer (score 1):

Typically on a Mac you would expect to find:

- /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
- /Library/Python

You should never touch the first, so the second exists to add local libraries.
What problem are you trying to solve by moving libraries?